# Different behavior of WPF Application: IDE debugging vs directly running the executable

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, squirrel.windows

I have a problem: different behavior of the same code (same .exe).

When I run my app in Debug mode (VS 2015), it behaves as expected.

Running this app in Release mode is also fine.

However, after packaging (packaging tool is **"NugetPackageExplorer.exe"**, I use Squirrel.windows to make and install .exe file), when I install my .exe, the application does not behave normally.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem? I'm so confused and can't solve this, since I can't use the debugger.

Thank you for reading my question. Please answer.

P.S. Before considering a downvote, please let know me the reason in the comments.

Comment: already i try Top MENU - > Debug -> Attach to Process.
after Attach to Process, it is so normal, but without debuger it isnt normal......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself.

[image]

few days ago, i modify Class Name IdleTimeFinder to NativeMethods.
IdleTimeFinder's role is just check the time that the user does not use PC.

after roll back all of code operate normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue in the past. It turns out that the heap is allocated differently if you run with the debugger attached. Here's the answer with details: [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144230/program-behave-abnormally-when-deployed/4144691#4144691). That said, turning off the debug heap didn't solve my problem (or advance my understanding of it).