# Massive memory leak in .NET6.0 dialog

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, .net-6.0

I have been chasing a memory leak and have gotten down to a pretty simple case. Whenever the canvas size changes, the window clears the canvas and adds 1,000 random points to the canvas. It also reports the memory usage in the titlebar of the window.
Memory starts out below 2MB.
If you grab the corner of the window and move it around a bit, the memory usage skyrockets to over 100MB in 10 sec. and the UI gets sluggish. Stop moving for 10 sec and the memory creeps back to 11MB (Not shown in the titlebar because there isn't an update but never back to the original <2MB).

Is it possible that simple wpf graphics are this broken? Am I doing something wrong? I call GC.Collect() on every repaint, so why does any memory recovery take so long?
Release/debug mode doesn't make any difference. Making the lines invisible doesn't make any difference. Changing line characteristics doesn't matter Using different color brushes on each line doesn't matter. The leak is proportional to the number of lines on the canvas.

How can it be that simple lines on a canvas aren't collected when the canvas is cleared?

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
<Window x:Class="SillyLeakTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
    <Canvas x:Name="theCanvas"/>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SillyLeakTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

  
        private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            Title = "Memory Used: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true).ToString("##,#");
          
            Point windowSize = new Point(theCanvas.ActualWidth, theCanvas.ActualHeight);
            Point center = new Point(windowSize.X / 2, windowSize.Y / 2);

            theCanvas.Children.Clear();
            
            SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)rand.Next(1, 255),
                (byte)rand.Next(1, 255), (byte)rand.Next(1, 255)));

            double scale = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Point p = new Point(rand.Next(-(int)center.X, (int)center.X), rand.Next(-(int)center.Y, (int)center.Y));
                theCanvas.Children.Add(new Line
                {
                    X1 = center.X + p.Y * scale,
                    Y1 = center.Y - p.X * scale,
                    X2 = center.X + p.Y + 2 * scale,
                    Y2 = center.Y - p.X + 2 * scale,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    //StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
                    //StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
                    // Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(P1.TheColor)
                    Stroke = color,
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not a wpf expert. But generally when things leak in c# its because you are not disposing of IDisposables correctly.

Comment: `Line` appears to be a mutable class. Why not have a `List<Line>` class-level, and re-assign the coordinates, if your use case requires re-drawing?

Comment: @pm100 it looks like `Line` is not an `IDisposable`, based on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.line?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)...

Comment: Interesing. I see that if I run it under VS profiler the size tops out at 3mb.

Comment: in fact running not under the debugger tops out at 2.8mb. I suspect its a side effect of having a debugger attached. Maybe CLR doesnt do forced GC collection when debugger attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I can confirm. WPF does some weird sht when debugger attached. Start without debugger via CTRL-F5

There is no screen decoration and the app runs smooth and fast , tops out at ~2.8mb.

Attach debugger from VS and suddenly we have a colored border and that strange debug panel at the top of the screen. Now the memory grows exponentially.

see [Different behavior of WPF Application: IDE debugging vs directly running the executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319445/different-behavior-of-wpf-application-ide-debugging-vs-directly-running-the-exe)

Comment: 0


Thanks a lot! I had assumed that just building in Release Mode would do the trick. Instead, you can build in Debug Mode, and start without debugger and it works like a champ. Bit of an issue though since chasing a bug takes a while and the updating dialogs quickly build up to multiple gigabytes. I hope they fix it.