# Using CMake, how do I get verbose output from CTest?

Tags: cmake, ctest

I'm using CMake to build my project. I have added a unit test binary which is using the Boost unit testing framework. This one binary contains all of the unit tests. I've added that binary to be run by CTest:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE( tftest test-main.cpp )
ENABLE_TESTING()
ADD_TEST( UnitTests tftest)
```

But the build output in Visual Studio only shows the result of running CTest:

```
      Start 1: UnitTests
  1/1 Test #1: UnitTests ................***Failed    0.05 sec

  0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1
```

This is not very helpful, because I can't see which test failed. If I run ctest manually from the command line with `--verbose` I get the output from a Boost unit test which tells what actually failed:

```
1: Test command: tftest.exe
1: Test timeout computed to be: 9.99988e+006
1: Running 4 test cases...
1: test-main.cpp(20): error in "sanity_check3": check 1 == 2 failed
1:
1: *** 1 failure detected in test suite "Master Test Suite"
1/1 Test #1: UnitTests ................***Failed    0.00 sec
```

So, what do I need to change in the CMakeLists.txt to have CTest run with `--verbose` at all times? Is there a better way to use Boost unit tests with CMake/CTest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace ctest command with "ctest --output-on-failure" permanently for a specific project in CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726545/replace-ctest-command-with-ctest-output-on-failure-permanently-for-a-specifi)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use the `ctest --output-on-failure` option, or set the environment variable [`CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#options), which will show you any output from the test program whenever the test fails. One way to do this when using Makefiles and the command line would be as follows:

```
env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 make check
```

[This Stack Overflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100543/how-do-i-set-specific-environment-variables-when-debugging-in-visual-studio/155363#155363) shows how to set environment variables in Visual Studio.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (ctest version 2.8.12.1). I tried `SET(CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE TRUE)` and `SET(CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE ON)`, but it has no effect. Other reports in the web corroborate that this is broken.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke `set(CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE TRUE)` doesn't set an *environment* variable.  Try this on the command line: `CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=TRUE make test`.

Comment: `make CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 test` is shorter and nicer IMO.

Comment: On windows batch file, how to use CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 while calling -- msbuild /toolsversion:15.0 /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 TESTS.vcxproj

Comment: Same as `--output-on-failure` according to the manual: [man 1 ctest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html).

Comment: @richq What's `make check`? And what I often see is `make test` other than `make check`.

Answer (score 64):

You could call `ctest` directly, after cmaking and making your project.

```
ctest --verbose
```

Comment: They mentioned that option in the original post but said they were looking to avoid having to run it manually.

Answer (score 41):

There is a very simple solution (which for some reason is difficult to find via Google Search):

```
ctest --output-on-failure
```

If you use CMake with Visual Studio's open folder function you can add the

```
"ctestCommandArgs": "--output-on-failure"
```

setting to your build configuration.

Comment: What if I want to output on success?

Answer (score 36):

1. You can check the `Testing/Temporary` subfolder. It is automatically created after running make test. This folder contains two files: `LastTest.log` and `LastTestsFailed.log`. `LastTest.log` contains desired output for run tests. `LastTestFailed.log` contains names of failed tests. So you can check them manually after executing `make test`.
2. The second way is to get ctest to show you the content of log files after running tests:

   1. place in *build dir* (from which you run `make test`) file CTestCustom.ctest (you can do it with *configure file* command, for example) with following contents

      CTEST_CUSTOM_POST_TEST("cat Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log")

Instead of cat you may use whatever Windows cmd command that does similar things.

2. run `make test` again and get profit!

additional info about customizing ctest you can find [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Testing_With_CTest). Just step to "Customizing cmake" section.
Good luck!

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was hoping there would be a way to modify the flags that are inserted into the project/makefiles for ctest, but I didn't find anything and your answer seems to confirm that.  The file name info is helpful!

Comment: somewhere around ctest 2.8.10 they have broken using external commands with arguments in CTEST_CUSTOM_POST_TEST    see https://github.com/openscad/openscad/issues/260

Comment: @don: maybe they aren't running enough tests on ctest ;-)

Comment: That CMake issue with CTEST_CUSTOM_POST_TEST is fixed in 2.8.12.

Comment: `CTEST_CUSTOM_POST_TEST("cat Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log")` does work. But it displays logs from previous CTest run :(

Answer (score 25):

This makes test output more verbose:

```
make test ARGS="-V"
```

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was looking for. This made sure that my output printed with `print_message` was shown even when all tests SUCCEEDED - otherwise I only saw those prints on failure.

Comment: IMO, this is the only correct answer. The "output on failure" answers do not qualify, as one may need to produce reports/results, in case of successful execution as well.

Answer (score 24):

I had to add "check" target by myself. "make tests" does nothing by some reason. So what I did (as was suggest somewhere on stackoverflow) - I added this target manually. To get verbose output I just wrote it like:

```
add_custom_target(check COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} --verbose)
```

Answer (score 21):

`make check CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=TRUE`

Comment: All the down-votes are rather surprising: this is almost equivalent to the accepted answer, but shorter and nicer. Also works in the project I tested.

Comment: make CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 test

Answer (score 11):

My approach is a combination of the answers [from ony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839353/3154588), [from zbyszek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28419351/3154588), and [from tarc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37123943/3154588). I use the `${CMAKE_COMMAND}` variable (which is set to the absolute path to the invoked cmake executable) with the `-E env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1` argument to invoke the actual ctest command using `${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -C $<CONFIG>`. To help clarify what is going on, I start with three `cmake -E echo` commands to show the current working directory and the ctest command to be invoked. Here is how I call `add_custom_target`.

```
add_custom_target(check 
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo CWD=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo CMD=${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -C $<CONFIG>
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ----------------------------------
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1
            ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -C $<CONFIG>
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    DEPENDS ALL_BUILD
    )
```

This plays nice with the MSVC IDE where any test errors are shown as clickable compilation errors. See [cmake -E env](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode) for documentation of the `cmake -E` portable command line tool mode. I also add a dependency on `ALL_BUILD` so that all projects will be built before invoking the `check` target. (On Linux builds, one may need to replace `ALL_BUILD` with `ALL`; I have not tested this on Linux yet.)

Answer (score 10):

There's now a CMake variable that allows you to modify the behaviour of `make test`. [CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS.html) lets you set a list of arguments to pass to ctest when run via `make test`.

So adding this to your CMake file (must be above `enable_testing()`):

```
set(CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS "--verbose")
```

Means CTest will always run verbose. Or for just the output of the failed tests, use:

```
set(CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS "--output-on-failure")
```

Edit:
As suggested by RobLoach, since it's a list of arguments, you'll want to append to the list instead.

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS "--output-on-failure")
```

Comment: Since it's a list of arguments, you'll want to append to the list...


list(APPEND CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS "--output-on-failure")

Answer (score 6):

For people using Visual Studio, here another variation (hack) on the theme:

```
cmake -E env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 cmake --build . --target RUN_TESTS
```

Answer (score 6):

`ctest -VV` or `ctest --extra-verbose`

From [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/ctest.1.html):

> Enable more verbose output from tests.
>
> Test output is normally suppressed and only summary information is
>   displayed. This option will show even more test output.

Answer (score -2):

to show the result with XML file you have to execute the test with the following command

```
~$ ctest -T Test
```

and we found the result in the Testing/1234123432/test.xml
and other files are generated too in Testing Folder

Comment: With -T there is some summary information in the XML, but it only includes the top tests, not individual test cases. Is there a way to also display those?