# CMake: setting an environmental variable for ctest (or otherwise getting failed test output from ctest/make test automatically)

Tags: testing, cmake, environment-variables, output, ctest

I want ctest to show me the failed tests output by default. That is, I want to run:

```
$ make all test
```

and see any output of failed tests without having to `cat Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log`.

It appears that there are two ways of doing this:

(1) Setting the `CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE` environmental variable:

```
 $ CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 make all test
 $ # or CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 ctest
```

(2) Specifying the `--output-on-failure` flag to the `ctest` invocation:

```
 $ ctest --output-on-failure
```

Is there a way to write a CMakeLists.txt file such that ctests dumps failed tests output by default on a normal "make all test" invocation WITHOUT resorting to exporting the environmental variable globally in the session or resorting to a custom target like `make check` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709914/using-cmake-how-do-i-get-verbose-output-from-ctest))?

I am aware of the `SET_TESTS_PROPERTIES()` command, but trying it out like this:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(testenv CXX)
ENABLE_TESTING()
ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello hello.cpp)
ADD_TEST(testhello hello)

# Following sets the environment variable for the shell in which the test
# progoram 'hello' is run, but not the shell in which ctest is run
SET_TESTS_PROPERTIES(testhello
    PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1")
```

and experimenting shows that the environmental variable is set in the shell that the test program is executed in, but not in the shell that ctest is executed in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace ctest command with "ctest --output-on-failure" permanently for a specific project in CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726545/replace-ctest-command-with-ctest-output-on-failure-permanently-for-a-specifi)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The built-in `test` target cannot be modified, but you can add a custom `check` target which invokes `ctest` with the `--output-on-failure` switch in the following way:

```
if (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
    add_custom_target(check COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} 
        --force-new-ctest-process --output-on-failure 
        --build-config "$<CONFIGURATION>")
else()
    add_custom_target(check COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} 
        --force-new-ctest-process --output-on-failure)
endif()
```

The custom target has to be set up differently for single build type and multi-configuration builds. In the latter case, the active build configuration has to be passed on to the `ctest` invocation using the `--build-config` flag. The `--force-new-ctest-process` is used by the built-in `test` target by default.

Comment: Thanks a heap, exactly what i was looking for! Any idea why it isn't possible to modify the `test` target?

Comment: The `test` target is one of CMake's global default targets which cannot be modified. The set up of the `test` command in hard-coded in the CMake source.

Comment: truly sad that it is not possible to just change the behavior of the test command by setting the option by default or setting an environment variable...

Comment: is there still no better option? this defeats the purpose of a simple commands like `GTEST_ADD_TESTS`.

Comment: At least with the Ninja generator, this doesn't print the test summaries during testing, only after all tests have run. Adding [`USES_TERMINAL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_target.html?highlight=uses_terminal) fixes this.

Comment: Note: I don't think the `if` is required. The first case will always work AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

There is now the list variable `CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS` in which you can set ctest arguments.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS.html

Comment: Is there some way to debug this? Because I've tried setting it in a variety of ways to no avail. I'm currently setting it in my test directory's CMakeLists.txt, and I've tried moving it around to various other positions within that, but there's no sign it does anything. I'm on version 3.20.2.

Comment: Ah, it needs to be set before any call to `enable_testing()`, just in case that's not obvious to people.