# TeamCity and CTest test results

Tags: teamcity, ctest

I have a number of unit tests written for my project, executed with CTest. I would like to integrate the results into my TeamCity build. I've downloaded and set up the plugin for my testing framework (Boost Test).

The problem that I have run into is that the tests run with CTest output to `Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log`, whereas TeamCity is trying to read the results from standard out. To get around this, my testing step is.

```
make test
cat Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log
```

which works, but feels like a hack.

Is there any way to get TeamCity to read from this file in addition to standard out? Alternatively, is there any way to tell ctest to output to standard out in addition to this LastTest.log file?

This question is similar, but I would like it to work for all output rather than just on failure: [CMake: setting an environmental variable for ctest (or otherwise getting failed test output from ctest/make test automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16158091/31455)

Answer (score 6):

Teamcity has additional build features which allow to process CTest reports. I am not sure if it'll work or not but you could try adding an additional build feature in your build step to read CTest report.

[image]