# Replace ctest command with "ctest --output-on-failure" permanently for a specific project in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, command, ctest

I have found that generic `ctest` command doesn't give much information about the tests, so I would like to add `ctest --output-on-failure` but not have the users to worry about the flag. I want them just to `cmake`, `make` the project and run ctest and it should run ctest **with** the `--output-on-failure` flag. Is it possible to do that in CMakeLists.txt?

**EDIT:**

Output of `env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 make test`

```
 4/13 Test  #4: TEST_SSSP ........................***Failed  Required regular expression not found.Regex=[CORRECT
]  0.00 sec
Loading Matrix-market coordinate-formatted graph ...
Input graph file /home/muhammad/gunrock/dataset/small/chesapeake.mtx does not exis
```

Output of `set_property(TEST TestName PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT "CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1")`

```
 4/13 Test  #4: TEST_SSSP ........................***Failed  Required regular expression not found.Regex=[CORRECT
]  0.00 sec
```

The flag in `set_property` is not working.

Comment: " This option can also be enabled by setting the environment variable CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE" https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/ctest.1.html

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus How would I permenantly set `CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE` to `true` in CMakeLists.txt? Is it just with a simple `set` command?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Nicolas! I ended up adding custom target `make check`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In CMake 3.17 [release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/release/3.17.html), there's a new variable [CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS.html) that you can set to pass any command-line arguments to CTest, including `--output-on-failure`. In your specific case, you can now simply add this to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS "--output-on-failure")
```

Answer (score 8):

I went with `make check` per solution: [CMake: setting an environmental variable for ctest (or otherwise getting failed test output from ctest/make test automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158091/cmake-setting-an-environmental-variable-for-ctest-or-otherwise-getting-failed)

```
add_custom_target(check ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1
                  ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -C $<CONFIG> --verbose
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```