# CMake verbose output from tests

Tags: cmake, ctest

How do I get "make test" to display verbose output? I want "make test" to do the same thing as ctest -V through the command line.

I have tried adding the following to my CMakeLists.txt, nothing worked :(

```
set(ENV{CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE} TRUE)

add_custom_target(check COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} --verbose)

add_custom_command(TARGET test PRE_BUILD
               COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -V)
```

But I still get this when I run make test:

```
  Start   1: unittest1
  1/143 Test   #1: unittest1 ....................................   Passed    0.01 sec
        Start   2: unittest2
  2/143 Test   #2: unittest2 ............................   Passed    0.03 sec
        Start   3: unittest3
  3/143 Test   #3: unittest3 ....................   Passed    0.02 sec
```

To clarify, I want to add something to my CMakeLists.txt to make this possible, I don't want a manual solution that requires me to append something to "make test" in the command line such as

```
CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=TRUE make test
```

or

```
ctest -V
```

<sub>My question is similar to *[Using cmake how do I get verbose output from ctest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709914/using-cmake-how-do-i-get-verbose-output-from-ctest)*.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [GNU Radio's wiki](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/OutOfTreeModules#Lets-try-that-running-make-test) page on doing tests on out-of-tree modules (courtesy of Mr. Braun):

Run `ctest -V` from the build directory (usually), and it will give you verbose information. Add `-R regex` to execute only tests that match `regex`.

Now, re-running a test on failure does seem to make a whole lot of sense to me -- and not automatically doing that on every `make test`, too, as tests might be time-consuming, and shouldn't be repeated in a broken build environment, etc. by default.

How to add that behaviour to the default `make test` behaviour of course depends on your CMake infrastructure, and I can't answer that without reading through your code.

Comment: Thanks! When I do ctest -V I get exactly the test output I want! How do I include the verbose flag into my CMakeLists.txt file so that "make test" automatically has verbose output

Comment: Thanks for the kind words; if you don't mind, I'd actually like an upvote ;)