# Errors when using make and cmake

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake

I'm following the procedure of "getting started" in the below link:

https://github.com/p4lang/p4c

managed to pass all the steps but when I got to

```
make -j4 check
```

I got the following error:

```
The following tests FAILED:
  2 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/action_call_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
  3 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/action_call_table_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
  4 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/bool_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
  5 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/count_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
  6 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/hit_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
  7 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/init_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
  8 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/issue870_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
  9 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/key-issue-1020_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
 10 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/key_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
 11 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/lpm_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
 12 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/stack_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
 13 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/switch_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
 14 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/test_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
 15 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/two_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
 16 - ebpf-kernel/testdata/p4_16_samples/valid_ebpf.p4 (Failed)
975 - p14_to_16/testdata/p4_14_samples/switch_20160512/switch.p4 (Timeout)
Errors while running CTest
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/check-all.dir/build.make:60: CMakeFiles/check- 
   all] Error 8

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:361: CMakeFiles/check-all.dir/all]     

Error2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:208: CMakeFiles/check.dir/rule] 

Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:227: check] Error 2
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You have all tests failed, and we could only **guess** about the reason(s) of fails. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709914/using-cmake-how-do-i-get-verbose-output-from-ctest) about obtaining more information about the reason of fails. And add this information into your question post.

Comment: Your issue seems to be addressed directly in the Github [here](https://github.com/p4lang/p4c/issues/1483).

Comment: not all test failed, most of them pass

Comment: Oh, I see, `ctest` actually prints only a failed tests. So what about the tests' output? Note, that Stack Overflow is not a place for *reporting bugs* for 3d party projects: address those reports into appropriate bug trackers.

Comment: I tried   ` ctest -R epbf-kernel -VV ` and I got   ` Error 2: Failed to compile the eBPF byte code:
14: /bin/sh: 1: clang: not found
`