# ctest: show output on timeout

Tags: fortran, ctest

I'm using cmake and ctest for testing.
Tests write their output to specific files, and i can include some debugging info if i want to. This works even when tests fail.

However, when tests time out (i think there is an infinite loop somewhere), the output files are created, but empty. I'm certain there should already be some output before the program gets stuck. I assume some writing buffer doesn't get flushed or something because of the timeout.

So now for my question: how can i get the output when the tests time out? Some way to get around the ctest output mechanism and write directly to the console would also be acceptible. I just need to be able to find out where in the code it gets stuck.

For reference, I'm talking about the tests in [this](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack) repository. I've also tried out the answers in [Using CMake, how do I get verbose output from CTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5709914/6422729) to no avail.

Edit: I really feel like an idiot now, I can just call the test executable directly