# Writing a Python functional test which requires a username and password

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, functional-testing, python-unittest

I have an API wrapper class `WfcAPI` written in Python 3 which I want to test using [PyUnit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html).

The `setUpClass()` for `WfcAPI` involves logging in to the external API server. The current functional test implementation has the password [obfuscated with Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/157975/3357935), but this is *far* from an ideal solution for security reasons.

```
import unittest
import base64
from pykronos import WfcAPI

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        password = base64.b64decode("U29tZVBhc3N3b3Jk").decode("utf-8")
        self.kronos = WfcAPI("SomeUsername", password)
```

I want to be able to quickly run functional tests for my API wrapper, but I also want to ensure that my username and password aren't included as part of the code.

**How can I setup a Python functional test for actions which require a username and password?**

Comment: can't you use, `password = input('Enter Passowrd')`

Comment: @harshil9968 If I were prompting the user for a password, I would want to hide the input with [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, does it work for you to use `pytest` instead of `unittest`?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf What would switching to pytest do?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, it will simplify your testing since you don't need to create a class which inherits from `unittest.TestCase`, in case of a `setUp` method, you can define a fixture. Finally, in my opinion. `pytest` makes testing simpler and more enjoyable =).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify: if it's a unit test, you shouldn't be testing against the real external API, you should Fake its response. A unit test should only be concerned with the Subject Under Test's logic (`WfcAPI`) and not its sub dependences.

Now, if you do a functional test where you send real data to the API, you can protect your credentials by storing them in an `.env` file which won't be commited with the rest of the code.

[This python library](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) offers that functionality and gives you an example in its Readme. You'd end up with something like this:

```
# .env

PASSWORD=some_password
USERNAME=SomeUsername
```

Then in your `settings.py`:

```
PASSWORD = os.environ.get("PASSWORD")
USERNAME = os.environ.get("USERNAME")
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the practical difference between a unit test and a functional test. I have been using `unittest` to test data returned from the API, as I want to make sure my sent requests work properly.

Comment: This may be helpful if you want to take a look at the differences: http://www.agilenutshell.com/episodes/41-testing-pyramid

But yeah, basically a unit test just tests a single function in your program. If you test against the response from an external API, it's probably better described as an integration/functional test. This is just terminology anyways.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that I am writing a functional test.

Comment: Related: [*Access environment variables from Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4906977/3357935) & [*How to set environment variables in PyCharm?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42708389/3357935)